# Exception on called function start() on mediPlayer class

Tags: android

i am using MediaPlayer class for android, and i make layout on activity_main.xml like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/screen" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:weightSum="7" >
        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="6" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip" >
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/bg" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/buttons" android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="5" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:gravity="center" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip" android:background="#FFFFFF" >
            <Button android:id="@+id/btnPrevious" android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/previous" android:layout_margin="5dp" 
                android:onClick="pauseradio" />
            <View android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="0dip" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/btnPlay" android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/play" android:layout_margin="5dp" 
                android:onClick="startradio" />
            <View android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="0dip" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/btnNext" android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/next" android:layout_margin="5dp" 
                android:onClick="stopradio" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

i set bg for my App but not appear on it, and i put button next and stop and previous for my media but not work.

my function to call it on button like this :-

```
public void startradio() {
    mp.start();
}

public void pauseradio() {
    mp.pause();
}

public void stopradio() {
    mp.stop();
}
```

**Edit :-**

iam using [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class but when my App start i have this error

```
04-25 19:06:23.323: I/dalvikvm(652): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-25 19:06:23.352: I/dalvikvm(652): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-25 19:07:52.862: D/gralloc_goldfish(702): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-25 19:07:52.892: W/TextLayoutCache(702): computeValuesWithHarfbuzz -- need to force to single run
04-25 19:08:32.603: D/AndroidRuntime(702): Shutting down VM
04-25 19:08:32.603: W/dalvikvm(702): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
04-25 19:08:32.633: E/AndroidRuntime(702): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 19:08:32.633: E/AndroidRuntime(702): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method pauseradio(View) in the activity class com.example.kam.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btnPrevious'
04-25 19:08:32.633: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3026)
04-25 19:08:32.633: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
04-25 19:08:32.633: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
04-25 19:08:32.633: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-25 19:08:32.633: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-25 19:08:32.633: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-25 19:08:32.633: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
04-25 19:08:32.633: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 19:08:32.633: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-25 19:08:32.633: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-25 19:08:32.633: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-25 19:08:32.633: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 19:08:32.633: E/AndroidRuntime(702): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: pauseradio [class android.view.View]
04-25 19:08:32.633: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
04-25 19:08:32.633: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
04-25 19:08:32.633: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3019)
04-25 19:08:32.633: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  ... 11 more
```

how can i call this function on my App on android.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the signature of your methods

```
public void startradio(View v) {
    mp.start();
}

public void pauseradio(View v) {
    mp.pause();
}

public void stopradio(View v) {
    mp.stop();
}
```

Comment: i try your solution, but when i load it we show this message :-
**radio is not responding. would you like to close it?**

Comment: Your problem (as it is) was solved. The problem you're talking about now is a different one and most likely depends on the rest of your code. For what it's worth: you are probably handling complex operations on your main thread which are blocking your app. But that has nothing to do with the question you asked right here.

Comment: and i see this exception when i click the button play after i click stop button :-
`04-25 19:38:15.487: E/MediaPlayer(535): start called in state 0
04-25 19:38:15.487: E/MediaPlayer(535): error (-38, 0)
04-25 19:38:15.487: E/MediaPlayer(535): Error (-38,0)`

Comment: That's to be expected. Look at this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#Valid_and_Invalid_States There you can see that after calling stop() your mediaplayer returns to the Stopped state. You can't call start() directly when in that state. As it is, your app probably won't work, unless you read the documentation.

Comment: First: this question has been solved. Mark it as such. Second: read the documentation I pointed you to. Third: Understand it. Fourth: Apply it.

Comment: ok but some problem solved and other not yet, like this message is not solved :- **radio is not responding. would you like to close it?**

Comment: Yeah, I guess it would be best. I'd be grateful if you'd mark this one as closed first, though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call Prepare on the mediaplayer object?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

See for life cycle info, also it really helps if you post the stack trace from the exception.

Comment: post the error that helps immensely, else we are just guessing